# Intercepting Angular form submission

Tags: angular, forms

I'm working on an Ionic/Angular application and need to implement this Pay360 cardlock library as specified here:

http://docs.pay360.com/cardlock/using-the-library/

I'm struggling to understand how I would use this library on my Angular form and how I would "intercept" the form submission as stated in those docs. How would I do this in my component, does anyone have any advice?

I have tried this in my template:

```
<form #myForm (ngSubmit)="payNow()" [formGroup]="paymentForm">
```

with the following in my component:

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: ElementRef;

let test = new CardLock({
            publishableId: xxx,
            formElementId: this.myForm.nativeElement,
            panElementId: xxx,
            tokenElementId: xxx,
            merchantAction: xxx
});
```

but this gives me an error for the formElementID attribute (as well as for the missing ones of course).  I also get an error if I remove the nativeElement bit.

Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: move it to ngAfterViewInit hook

Comment: Thanks but I'm running the code on the press of a "Pay" button so this is all after ngAfterViewInit has fired

Comment: Try @ViewChild('myForm', {read: ElementRef })